# Как получить данные из зашифрованного(?) json?

Tags: json, xhr

Есть некий сайт, который подгружает данные динамически. В инструментах разработчика в браузере, в XHR запросах нашел, какую именно инфу он еще подгружает для корретного отображения страницы. Получил эту же инфу на Python запросом и сохранил в файл. Однако что в файле, что на вкладке Preview в инструметах разработчика, отображается странный набор символов, как будто этот ответ зашифрован, что-то вроде такого:

```
SA÷1¬~ZA÷АВСТРАЛІЯ: А-Ліга¬ZEE÷OjWW1naM¬ZB÷24¬ZY÷Австралія¬ZC÷rB1LBFN8¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷rLiJR28j¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷24_OjWW1naM¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/soccer/australia/a-league/¬OAJ÷EB34qFYI-2BbkEDeI.png¬ZX÷00Австралія   009тралія0000000000001000А-Ліга      006А-Ліга000¬ZCC÷0¬TSS÷¬ZAF÷Австралія¬~AA÷4vhLe9e3¬AD÷1708416000¬ADE÷1708416000¬AB÷1¬CR÷1¬AC÷1¬CX÷Мельбурн Вікторі¬RW÷0¬AX÷0¬BX÷-1¬WL÷¬WQ÷¬WM÷МВІ¬AE÷Мельбурн Вікторі¬FH÷Мельбурн Вікторі¬JA÷E3BzmdaT¬GRA÷0¬OA÷bkKBUbQq-jm1g2SD5.png¬WN÷ВЕС¬AF÷Вестерн Юнайтед¬FK÷Вестерн Юнайтед¬JB÷Wrb2rG7p¬GRB÷0¬OB÷hrr7qKoe-G689Zsd3.png¬AL÷{"2":[{"BU":"\/bookmaker\/16\/?from=live-streaming&sport=1","IU":"https:\/\/static.flashscore.com\/res\/image\/data\/bookmakers\/17-16.png","BN":"bet365","BI":16,"BT":"Дивіться спортивні події live на bet365! Застосовуються регіональні обмеження. Необхідна наявність ігрового рахунку з коштами або ставки зробленої протягом останніх 24 годин. BeGambleAware.org. 18+"},
```

И так далее. Строка очень длинная. Еще на основной странице обнаружил упоминание о некоем токене (если это может быть полезно в данном случае):

```
window.loggingServiceConfig = {"enable":true,"server":"https:\/\/logging-service.livesport.services\/","token":"Y3uhIv5Ges46mMdAZm53akso95sYOogk","percentage_of_sessions_to_log":1};
```

Вопрос в том, можно ли расшифровать то, что прииходит в результате запроса?

Comment: Наверное можно. Если исходный сайт это получает и расшифровывает. А делает он это вероятней всего с помощью javascript - а значит можно попробовать проанализировать код и понять алгоритм.